# Model geometry distortion when camera moves to the side

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a loaded model what looks good from the front but if i move the camera to the side the model looks kinda strange ( fat :) ). Am I doing something wrong or it is normal with perpective camera view angle at 80 ?

Here is the 2 image:

front: http://i48.tinypic.com/14tbg7.jpg

side: http://i47.tinypic.com/scric7.jpg

and the loader code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( model_js, function( geometry ) {

    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textura);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { morphTargets: true,map: texture } );
    meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry,material );                        

    meshAnim.scale.set( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    morphs.push( meshAnim );

    scene.add( meshAnim );       
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal with a perspective view angle of 80. Set it to 45 or so. Experiment with a sphere mesh.